# chrome.runtime.getURL() unable to inject javascript file into my webpage for manifest V3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, manifest.json

**Background:** I'm making a chrome extension, and I must migrate it to MV3. I modified my manifest.json file to include web resources, but when I go to inject my resource from my content script using chrome.runtime.getURL, it says it can't find my file. Specifically...

***GET: Chrome-extension:://"the_url/inject_script.js" net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND***

I'm using the content root path to my web resource (javascript elements I want to inject onto the page), which is what I read needed to be used when using MV3. Below is my manifest file.

**Manifest.json**

```
 {
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Extension Prototype",
  "description": "Prototype for Canvas Extension",
  "version": "0.1.0",

  "icons": {
  },

  "web_accessible_resources": [{
    "resources": ["frontend/canvas-chrome-ext/src/scripts/inject_script.js"],
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
  }],

  "action": {
    "default_popup": "components/popup.html",
    "default_icon": "images/su_emblem.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "<all_urls>",
    "tabs",
    "scripting"
  ],

  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },

  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["https://seattleu.instructure.com/", "*://www.google.com/", "https://canvas.instructure.com/*"],
    "js": ["scripts/Content.js"]
  }]
}
```

**Content Script**

Below is my content script, which is supposed to create a scrip DOM element. The script (inject_script.js) element injects some buttons onto the webpage.

```
function injectScript(file_path, tag){
    var node = document.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0];
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('src', file_path);
    node.appendChild(script);
}

injectScript(chrome.runtime.getURL("frontend/canvas-chrome-ext/src/scripts/inject_script.js"), 'body');
```

**Below is my project directory.**

[image]

Comment: You need to use the final path in the dist folder that appears after you build the project. It'll be probably `scripts/inject_script.js`

Comment: Dang thanks I changed the path from the content root to scripts/inject_scripts.js in the web resources and my reference when using runtime.getURL and it worked. Side note what and where is my dist folder in my directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wOxxOm answer helped me.

I was using the content root path to reference my inject_script, but I should have been using the final path in the dist folder instead.